# How do I troubleshoot a fan light that cycles on/off?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I've have a Hunter ceiling fan (Brenham Model 50033) for over 1.5 years and it's worked fine.
Today it started acting up.

[image]

#### Problem

The light cycles bright and then turns off and returns and goes bright.  The fan momentarily turns off when the light turns off.  This continues forever but happens at a slow cycle (10-180 seconds).

#### Troubleshooting

This model has a ceiling fan and a light with a remote shown below

[image]

**Light Features**

- The light can be turned on or off by pressing the remote control button once.
- Or the light brightness can cycle from bright to dim and back by holding the light button on the remote.

**Fan Features**

- The fan can be turned on or off by pressing the fan button on the remote.
- Or the arrow buttons can control the speed of the fan (faster or slower).

### What I've tried.

- I first thought it was the remote, so I checked the remote batteries and it was fine.
- I removed the remote batteries, turned the power to the fan off (left it for 30 seconds) and turned the power back on.   The problem remained with the light cycling.

**I'm looking for the next set of suggestions for troubleshooting and fixing this problem.**

Comment: sounds like the remote receiver in the ceiling

Comment: If you hold a light brightness button to cause the light to cycle, A) does the light turn off (when getting dimmer), then come back on at full brightness? B) Does the fan shut off momentarily when you reach the bottom or top of the brightness?

Comment: When holding the "light button" on the remote, the light does respond and cycle (more quickly) and the fan doesn't shut off (when I reach the top brightness).  The fan never momentarily shut off when the light reached the max dimness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooting this problem involves isolating the problem (if possible):

1. Check voltages being received by the fan to make sure they are consistent and not oscilating.
2. Change the light bulbs to make sure there isn't a problem with the bulb that is causing the cycling.
3. Change the batteries in the remote and make sure that the remote isn't causing the problem.
4. Change the receiver in the fan assembly (this unit receives a signal from the remote to control the fan and the light).

Answer (score 1):

A very common problem with Hunter fans is the [thermal limiter](https://www.reddit.com/r/electricians/comments/4erbjb/found_the_problem_in_my_hunter_fanlight_can_i/) component being faulty and turning off power to the lights, even if they are fitted with efficient light bulbs. You may want to measure resistance across this component during the temporary outage phase and see if it indicates the limiter has activated.